# Generate sublists of list A by grouping according to list B

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have:

```
a = [939, 84, 100, 338, 281, 94, 884, 848]
b = ["red", "green", "orange", 'blue']*2
zip_list = zip(a, b)
```

Which returns:

```
[(939, 'red'), (84, 'green'), (100, 'orange'), (338, 'blue'), (281, 'red'), 
(94, 'green'), (884, 'orange'), (838, 'blue')]
```

From here my goal is to obtain:

```
   # blue #   # green # # orange #   # red #
[ [338, 838], [84, 94], [100,884], [939, 281] ]
```

That is, a new list derived from list a, grouped by list b (note the alphabetical order).

The length of unique elements in `b` will always be a factor (mathematical sense) of the length of `a`, e.g., `len(a) == 8` & `len(unique(b)) == 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt which uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> import itertools
>>> sorted_zip_list = sorted(zip_list, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> sorted_zip_list
[(338, 'blue'), (848, 'blue'), (84, 'green'), (94, 'green'), (100, 'orange'), (884, 'orange'), (939, 'red'), (281, 'red')]
>>> result = []
>>> for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_zip_list, itemgetter(1)):
...     result.append([e[0] for e in g])
...
>>> result
[[338, 848], [84, 94], [100, 884], [939, 281]]
```

I sort `zip_list` first so `groupby` can be used. `itemgetter` was imported for convenience and can be replaced with `lambda e: e[1]`

But in general you should use TigerhawkT3's approach with `OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 1):

using a defaultdict is what I would go for..
You specify in the argument to defaultdict what the type of value for your keys would be.

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for key, val in zipped:

     d[key].append(val)
```

the sorting can be obtained by:

`{k:v for k,v in sorted(d.items())}`